# RequestAnimationFrame in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, asynchronous

I'm implementing a pretty straight-forward animation in LWC (Lightning Web Components). My normal approach to doing animations within JS is to use requestAnimationFrame, but the linter rules in LWC complain if using any async code.

**Is this going to cause problems for me later?** It works perfectly fine right now, but does seem dangerous! Should I take a different approach?

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class GnPulseScore extends LightningElement {

    @track displayedScore = 0;

    @api
    get score() {
        return this.internalScore;
    }

    // Whenever the score changes, animate the change. This will increment displayScore until it matches internalScore visually
    set score(value) {
        this.internalScore = parseInt(value, 10);
        this.animate();
    }

    internalScore = 100;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.animate = this.animate.bind(this);
    }

    animate(timestamp) {
        const displayedScore = parseInt(this.displayedScore, 10);
        const score = parseInt(this.internalScore, 10);

        if (displayedScore !== score) {
            if (displayedScore > score) {
                this.displayedScore = this.displayedScore - 1;
            } else {
                this.displayedScore = this.displayedScore + 1;
            }
            // Potentially Dangerous!!
            window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<c-gn-pulse-score score="100"></c-gn-pulse-score>
```

A playground link with this implemented can be viewed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/MDDpmBbVj/32/edit) (please note: there is a workaround in place due to playground limiting `.bind`)

Comment: can you create a playground link and share?

Comment: Oh, that's a fantastic idea, I didn't think of that, doing that now!

Comment: Added the playground: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/MDDpmBbVj/25/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have any doubts with respect to **SecureWindow or SecureDocument**, you can check [Locker API Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer).

> ***requestAnimationFrame*** is supported for API 46. As LWC as a framework is not yet stabilized/fully mature as of today, we are getting console warnings/errors even for standard features. We need not worry as long as the documentation supports our implementation. Even if something does not work as stated in documentation, it will be a bug and will be fixed by salesforce.

**However, you are getting console WARNING because:**

> The reason you are getting warning is because async javascript will have the problem of memory leak if not handled properly. For example when you use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), you should also use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) to avoid memory leak. As developers tend to not clear the interval, the memory tends to build up with time and after few hours without window refresh the performance is affected drastically. Coming to [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), you should use [cancelAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame) whenever necessary. I said ***when necessary*** because it is not mandatory to cancel the requestAnimationFrame in your case because you have a definitive range in which you want to run it and after that range it will not be invoked. However it is still better to cancel the request at the end of range.

**Supported:**

[image]

**Not Supported:**

[image]

Comment: It is supported. But it does give a lint warning about the async nature, *that* is the problem I'm worried about, if it will mess up the lifecycle events within LWC

Comment: @Mattisdada. Given the reason for warning.